# Pimsleur Mandarin Chinese vs Pimsleur Digital Mandarin Chinese

Tags: chinese, pimsleur-courses

I'm using Pimsleur audiobooks via Audible.com to help learn Mandarin.

There seem to be 2 different series, "Pimsleur Digital Mandarin Chinese" and "Pimsleur Mandarin Chinese" but I can't find any explanation of the distinction.

Does anyone know what the difference is, so that I'll know which ones I want to keep buying?

Here is a screenshot of the different series:

[image]

Comment: Could you please share a link to "Digital" product.  My search for "digital mandarin" on audible.com shows nothing.

Comment: @Vitaly  In the past you would just search for Mandarin and see both. Since this question was written 10 months ago they consolidated or replaced the 2 series on Audible with one that has new cover art. I could show you screen shots of the ones I bought or you could just search Google to see them.

Comment: @Vitaly I just added a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it's the same product under a different front cover. Pimsleur added the word "digital" when they started offering downloadable MP3 files in addition to audio CDs.

Pimsleur products for all languages are structured in the same way. The full course consists of levels numbered 1,2,3... Level 1 being the easiest. Chinsese program consists of 5 levels currently. Each level contains 30 half-hour-long units.

For your studying just ensure that you progress from lower level to the higher, from lower unit to higher unit.

Comment: But I own the first lesson of both and the content was a little different

Comment: @Hack-R That's interesting. Some programs did go through multiple editions over years. But both of your editions are dated the same year - 2010. I only see the "Digital" version offering one lesson only, so I would continue with the other "non-digital" : -) version.